# Including extra information in PUT response

Tags: rest, http

Is it ok to return extra information in http `PUT` response such as `createdDateTime` or `lastUpdateTime`

E.g. PUT request comes as follows

```
properties
{
     "name": "somename"
     "addr": "someaddr"
}
```

In response along with sending the resource representation I am sending extra information

`HTTP OK or CREATED`

```
properties
    {
         "name": "somename"
         "addr": "someaddr"
         "lastUpdateTime": "somedatetime"
    }
```

Is this a bad practice ?

Comment: Unless the information is absolutely required, don't send it as it only gives more info to people that want to find vulnerabilities.

Comment: What @SSNR said. Also, it sounds like this is informatiom that your backend should already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with that. If the client needs that information, then the resource will have to include it as a property. The client can `POST`/`PUT` without it (NULL), or the server will ignore it anyway (since this is only set server-side), but it will have to reflect it afterwards.

You can always secure your API if you're going to expose it publicly (OAuth, API keys etc).